# ReactJs displays error Cannot read property setState of undefined with Axios form submission

Tags: reactjs

ReactJs displays the error:

> Cannot read property setState of undefined.

I know that this question has been asked more often but most solutions I found  do not address my current problem.

This code below was used to post files to server and it works fine. Now If I implement the code below immediately after the Axios response returns:

```
this.setState({
    filename:res.data.filename,
    message:res.data.message,
});
```

It will display said error. Please which `setState` do I need to bind

**Here is the code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import axios, { post } from 'axios';

class FilePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value:'', 
      filename:'',
      myfile:'',
      submitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ submitted: true });

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myfile', $('#myfile')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('filename', $('#filename').val());

    axios
      .post('http://localhost/api.php', formData)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          filename:res.data.filename,
          message:res.data.message,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { submitted } = this.state;
    var style1 = {
      background: 'green',
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 30
    };

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  id="myform">
        <label>
         <div style={style1}> Testing Data </div>
         <input className="form-control" name="myfile" type="file" id="myfile" value={this.state.myfile} onChange={this.handleChange} />
         <b>filename:</b><input tyle="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.filename}  name="filename" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `function(res)` disconnects the `this` context in your success callback, use an arrow function there (same goes for `function(err)` but you are not referring to `this`at that time. Also, when you look for help, take some effort in formatting your code, cause as it is at the moment it's quite a jumble...

Comment: Please Icepickle can you illustrate with example

Comment: I am sorry but if this is not clear how `this` scope is handled, then you really should learn javascript and scopes / context a bit more in detail. In the meantime, an answer got added that gives you a solution, though it might not directly expand on the why. It is by far not the only problem in your code (though the problems I would be referring to would be react specific things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope inside the `function(res)` is changed. Try this instead.

```
axios.post('http://localhost/api.php', formData)
            .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);

           this.setState({
           filename:res.data.filename,
           message:res.data.message,

         });
```